# Twig extract FOR loop variables

Tags: twig, symfony

Say I have a collection of items

```
$collection = array(
      'item1' => array(
            'post' => $post,
            'category' => $category,
            // ...
  ),
  'item2' => array(...)
);
```

And I have a template:

```
{% for item in collection %}

    Now I can use item data
       - {{ item.post.title }}
       - {{ item.category.id }}
       - {{ item.var1 }}
       - {{ item.var2 }}
       - and another 20 vars

    I want to extract those vars into more global FOR context, and use them as:

        {{ post.title }}
        {{ category.id }}
        {{ var1 }}
         ... etc

{% endfor %}
```

Is this possible?

I was thining of defining the loop as a template block and then iterating it with Twig_Template::renderBlock(). But the docs say renderBlock is for 'internal' use only :) So not sure.

EDIT:

Another idea I had:

```
{% for item in collection %}

    {% do extract(item) %}
    // extract() would work similar to extract function from php

{% endfor %}
```

However, it seems that context is passed to twig functions by value, so this would not work.

Lastly I could write a TokenParser and do:

```
{% for item in collection %}

    {% extract item %}
    // would probably get direct access to the context, but haven't tried it

{% endfor %}
```

But this is quite a bit of work.. I am just hoping that twig can already do this natively :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro :
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

```
{% import _self as macro %}

{% macro render(item) %}
    {{ item.post.title }}
    {{ item.category.id }}
    {{ item.var1 }}
    {{ item.var2 }}
    ...
{% endmacro %}

{% for item in collection %}
   {{ macro.render(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem? I still have to access each item by `{{ item.xxxx }}`

Comment: Here it is scoped on the macro parameter.

So if you call {{ macro.render(foo) }} it will render the foo components.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to assign variables in the global context :

```
{% for item in collection %}
    {% for var, value in item %}
        {% set  _context[var] = value %}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ post.title }}
    {{ category.id }}
    {{ var1 }}
     ... etc
{% endfor %}
```